# String copy with strcpy_s

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Trying to copy string using `strcpy_s`

```
char foo[10];  // a buffer able to hold 9 chars (plus the null)
char bar[] = "A string longer than 9 chars";
strcpy_s( foo, 10, bar );
```

Got Assertion:

```
Expression: (L"Buffer is too small" && 0)
```

Can't understand why. `foo` has space for 10 characters and second parameter is 10. So, what is wrong?

Comment: Could this be because of the \0 ?

Comment: You want `strncpy` (lookup the documentation for both)

Comment: foo has only space for 10 characters and the source is more than 10 characters, so you are getting buffer too small error

Comment: Because you have used _s function which means "secure" copy, it checked for size

Comment: @DieterLücking - no, `strncpy` is not appropriate. In this case it will quietly copy the first 10 characters from `bar` into `foo` with no nul terminator. That's a disaster waiting to happen. There are very few situations where `strncpy` is actually useful. Read its documentation **carefully**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour

in docs you have:

> numberOfElements
>   Size of the destination string buffer in char units for narrow and multi-byte functions, and wchar_t units for wide functions.

so second parametr is the size of your destination buffer. And function tries to copy all characters from the source.

If you want to copy as many as possible elements using *_s function then consider using:

```
strncpy_s(foo, sizeof(foo)/sizeof(foo[0]), bar, _TRUNCATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
errno_t strcpy_s(
   char *strDestination,
   size_t numberOfElements,
   const char *strSource 
);
```

> The strcpy_s function copies the contents in the address of strSource, including the terminating null character, to the location that's specified by strDestination. The destination string must be large enough to hold the source string and its terminating null character. The behavior of strcpy_s is undefined if the source and destination strings overlap.

From MSDN documentation, if the destination is not large enough, you will get error.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing as much characters as the buffer could contain. As stated [in the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy):

> 2) Same as (1), except that it may clobber the rest of the destination
>   array with unspecified values and that the following errors are
>   detected at runtime and call the currently installed constraint
>   handler function:
>
> [...]
>
> **destsz is less or equal strnlen_s(src, destsz)**; in other words, truncation would occur
>
> [...]

You fall in the "equal" case, thus the error. If you known what you do, you can ignore it or enable truncation.